# Is there a more idiomatic way to handle this controller logic in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  def index
    @workouts = Workout.all
    @user_workouts = current_user.workouts.order("created_at DESC") unless current_user.blank?
    if @client.present?
      @user_workouts = @client.workouts.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @workouts }
    end
  end
```

The issue in question here is the instance variable `@user_workouts` - I am using a nested route to be able to do something like /clients/1/workouts instead of /workouts which will show the current users workouts which if that were nested would be /users/1/workouts.

Any idiomatic way to handle this or is it normal to just let the conditionals creep in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a class method on `Workout` accepting a `User` instance

```
def self.for_user(user)
  where(user_id: user.id).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

and then simplify your action

```
def index
  @workouts      = Workouts.all
  @user_workouts = Workout.for_user(@client || current_user)

  respond_to ...
```

If `@client` exists it will be passed to `for_user`, otherwise `current_user` will.

Answer (score 1):

You could DRY it up a little with:

```
user = @client || current_user
@user_workouts = user.workouts.order("created_at DESC")
```

Other than that, it looks pretty good as-is.